# Withdraw failed with "transaction revert" error solidity compiler ^0.8.4

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, hardhat, ethers.js

I am writing my first smart contract, it's very barebone with two functions deposit and withdraw. Testing using hardhat and etherjs

```
contract test {
mapping(address => uint256) balances;

function deposit(uint256 amount) external payable {
    balances[msg.sender] += amount;
}

function withdraw() external {
    uint256 amount = balances[msg.sender];
    balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
    require(success, "Transfer failed.");
}

function balanceOf(address account) public view virtual returns (uint256) {
    return balances[account];
}
}
```

Testing it with etherjs + hardhat and transactions getting reverted, pls help, what I am missing here.

below is the test case

```
  it("TEST CONTRACT", async function () {

Contract= await ethers.getContractFactory("test");
testContract= await Contract.deploy();

await expect(testContract.connect(add1).deposit(100));
expect(await testContract.connect(add1).balanceOf(player1.address)).to.equal(100);
expect(await testContract.connect(add1).withdraw()); // Basically transaction revert from here
console.log('Balance ', add1.address, (await testContract.balanceOf(add1.address)).toNumber())
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your `deposit` function doesnt ensure the amount added to the user's balance is the amount that is actually transferred. One could for example call this function with `amount` = 100 ETH and actually send only 1 wei to the contract, its balance within the contract would be set to 100 eth regardless (which would naturally lead to a revert when you call the withdraw function in that case, and imagining the contract lives on mainnet and is actually used, would lead to exploits). You'd want to use `msg.value` instead of `amount` here
`balances[msg.sender] += amount;`

Comment: Hey @Foxxxey, I understand the problem statement, but changing it to your suggestion doesn't help. basically, I want to send some eth/token to a smart contract, contract will keep them for some time then allow refund/withdrawal based on some events.

Comment: Hey @Foxxxey Thanks for setting me in the right direction, I was trying to send eth to this deposit function using ethers, and doing it wrong. Followed ethers contract/signer/provider documentation here https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signTransaction helped. Thanks